# Unable to use != operator in informatica

Tags: informatica

I am unable to use '!=' operator for lookup in Informatica.
It gives me same result as with '=' operator.
Am I missing on something?

Comment: No, actually "!=" operator is Pre-defined in their database so symbol is not the issue.
It's just that it is not giving me desired result.

Comment: Which lookup are you using in informatica? Connected or unconnected

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 Check the lookup values in the database and your source value as well. Compare both the results and find the issue. You can also filter the lookup data by provide lookup override query to increase the performance

[image]